# Unable to inflate a custom view in activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate a custom view in activity onCreateView

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    TextView text = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    text.setText("Hello World");
    return rootView;
```

> I am getting stack overflow error

Comment: You probably don't need to be overriding the `Activity`'s `onCreateView()` method. Inflate your custom `View` in `onCreate()`, and either set it as the content `View`, or add it to a `ViewGroup` in the layout you're setting as the content.

Comment: @MikeM. I am sure and know it works that way but still cannot understand whats wrong with this approach ?

Comment: An `Activity`s `onCreateView()` method is not like a `Fragment`'s, and you can't use it the same way you would in a `Fragment`. Check the docs for that method's description. Just do your inflation in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way I was able to inflate a custom view :)

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_world, container, false);
        return layout;
    }
```